# Suggestion on matplotlib colors : Need distinct shades.

Tags: colors, matplotlib, plot, voronoi

I'm plotting a voronoi diagram in which I shade the polygons depending on a proportional probability( By which I mean, If I were  to plot give polygons their total probability might be 1).This is my code where I give the facecolor as the probability value. [image]

```
matplotlib.patches.Polygon(poly, facecolor= probList[i])
```

The problem is the shades are not distinct enough to reflect my probability values. I'm fine with going any colors as long as the shades reflect probability.StackOverflow ppl, please throw in your suggestions.Thanks!

Comment: If you are downvoting,it is generally a good practice to mention in comments on why you're doing so.Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Picking from **[matplotlibs colormaps](http://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)** is probably a good start.  The link shows all of the preset colormaps.

My favorites (and a common choice) for **ordered values** (like probability, which goes from zero to one) are `hot` or `afmhot`, because they show good distinction of intermediate values and have clear perceptual ordering.

Below are the sequential colormaps from matplotlib (taken from the reference above).  Or, see the full set (again, at the reference above) if you want more distinction at the cost of less obvious ordering.  (Even if you choose to not use a sequential colormap, you might still want to avoid the unfortunately popular `jet` colormap because, amongst other reasons, it starts and ends with dark colors, making it hard to understand).

[image]
[image]